# Cluj-Napoca to Sighisoara

Tags: routes, romania

I want to travel from Cluj-Napoca to Sighisoara and I don't know which is the better route, through Medias or through Targu Mures. Better route meaning:

1. Good road
2. Nice landscape

Comment: Traditionally we accept questions about most scenic route. "Best" is always bad, unless qualified. Here it's qualified but the OP seems to have put in little effort. What routes are you aware of, did you check already on your own? What makes a "good" road?